# The right way to model entities in KeyCloak

Tags: security, authorization, keycloak

What is the correct way to model authorization in KeyCloak?

We would like to model:

- Who is allowed
- On what peace of data
- What kind of action to do

For example, does the user Bob [who] can edit [action] a note title [peace of data]?

Comment: This is very broad question,cant be answer .You can read about ACL(Access Control). How to control user operations.

Comment: You need to be more clear on what are your resources for which you want to provide authorization.